# R-commander. Generate random data depending on the means and SDs of different populations

Tags: r, random-generation

I have 3 different populations, represented by their specific means and SDs. So I have 3 means with their 3 SDs:

Mean1 = 5.5  SD1 = 0.65

Mean2 = 5.9  SD2 = 0.32

Mean3 = 5.4  SD3 = 0.49

If I want to obtain a sample size (n) of 1000 randomly of each population according to their respective means and SDs, how can I do it in only one step using for example R commander?

So I want 3 columns of 1000 samples each.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In order to draw a random sample you need to specify the distribution from which these samples need to be drawn, e.g. a normal distribution, gamma distribution, Laplace distribution, ... So, which distribution do you want to use?

Comment: It was a normal distribution Maarten Buis, I forgot to comment but Theja glimpsed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want Gaussians: here is a dataframe in R:

```
 data.frame(pop1 = rnorm(1000,mean=5.5,sd=0.65), pop2 = rnorm(1000,mean=5.9,sd=0.32), pop3 = rnorm(1000,mean=5.4,sd=0.49))
```

Comment: And one more question. How can I simulate each of the three last populations 30 times without writing rnorm(1000,M1,SD1) thirty times?

Comment: There are many ways. Use a for loop like for (i in 1:30) { ... } . Or if you want a matrix popX for each population X (X=1,2,3) with number of rows being 1000 and number of columns being 30 (and you can index each sample by popX[,sampleNumber]), then do popX = matrix(rnorm(1000*30,mean=MX,sd=SDX),nrow=1000).